# How can i set more than one java_path on windows

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't setup eclipse.When i try to run eclipse setup file i'm getting this error "***Version 1.7.0_80 of the JVM is not suitable for this product.Version 1.8 or greater is required***" and i can't reconfigure java_home path because i'm using jasper ireport and i'm billing every day for my company and it's very critical program for me. If i chance the path jasper doesn't working, jasper working only 1.7 java version and I do not want to change the java path every time.So how can i set two java path ? I don't wanna try anything because if i make a mistake there will be a big problem.I need exact solution.Please help me.Sorry about my bad language

Comment: Add another one separated with an ";"

Comment: Edit the eclipse.ini and use the `-vm` option - see [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

Comment: there is no eclipse.ini file. I couldn't setup eclipse and i'm typing java -version in cmd it's seems 1.8 version and i tried "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre";"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre" like you sad Mark  it's now working too